# How do I find which Website has a particular hostname

Tags: iis-6, iis

I want to find which website listed in the IIS 6 Manager has a particular host header value configured in its identities. Currently I have to go through each website, right click properties, Web Site tab, Advanced button, then scroll through the list there to see if this website has the host name I'm searching for. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save yourself the hassle of looking through each website:  You can directly open the metabase.xml (%windir%\system32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml) with your favorite editor.  The MetaBase stores much of the IIS6 configuration including the bindings... from there, you can search for whatever host header (binding) you are looking for.

Side Note: Do not attempt to edit this file without enabling [direct metabase editing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997548%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx)!

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This was the only answer found when looking the same but for IIS 7.5. Problem is it does not help for IIS 7.5. In case someone else needs it, adding answer when IIS 7.5:

Find the domain

ApplicationHost.config

in

%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config folder.